# Find and count equal dicts inside a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count, repeat

I have a list with multiple dicts in, I need to check which dicts are repeated and create a new list with only a single occurrence of each but with the amount of repeated elements in the first list.

For example:

I have that list:

```
[{'a': 123, 'b': 1234, 'c': 'john', 'amount': 1},
 {'a': 456, 'b': 1234, 'c': 'doe','amount': 1},
 {'a': 456, 'b': 1234, 'c': 'steve','amount': 1},
 {'a': 123, 'b': 1234, 'c': 'john','amount': 1},
 {'a': 123, 'b': 1234, 'c': 'john','amount': 1}]
```

I need to output:

```
[{'a': 123, 'b': 1234, 'c': 'john', 'amount': 3},
{'a': 456, 'b': 1234, 'c': 'steve','amount': 1},
{'a': 456, 'b': 1234, 'c': 'doe','amount': 1}]
```

I've tried some things I found by Googling but nothing works completely, the last that I've tried let me know where the repeated ones where, but I'm stuck in what to do next.

```
def index(lst, element):
    result = []
    offset = -1
    while True:
        try:
            offset = lst.index(element, offset+1)
        except ValueError:
            return result
        result.append(offset)

for i in l:
    if len(index(l,i)) > 1:
        i['amount'] += 1
print l
```

But it returns

```
[{'a': 123, 'c': 'john', 'b': 1234, 'amount': 2}, 
 {'a': 456, 'c': 'doe', 'b': 1234, 'amount': 1}, 
 {'a': 456, 'c': 'steve', 'b': 1234, 'amount': 1}, 
 {'a': 123, 'c': 'john', 'b': 1234, 'amount': 2}, 
 {'a': 123, 'c': 'john', 'b': 1234, 'amount': 1}]
```

Comment: Have you tried `collections.Counter` ?

Comment: @Daenyth yes, I did, but becacuse it's a list of dicts it doesnt work TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using pandas by which we can concatenate the dictionary into a data frame, and then we can groupby column a, b and c and calculate the sum of amount. And if we want a dictionary back, pandas data frame has a built in `to_dict()` function. Specifying the parameter as `index`, we can get a dictionary as the desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
list(pd.DataFrame(mylist).groupby(['a', 'b', 'c']).sum().reset_index().to_dict('index').values())

# [{'a': 123, 'amount': 3, 'b': 1234, 'c': 'john'},
#  {'a': 456, 'amount': 1, 'b': 1234, 'c': 'doe'},
#  {'a': 456, 'amount': 1, 'b': 1234, 'c': 'steve'}]
```

Comment: Thanks man, I think that pandas will be my favorite lib for a while <3

Comment: Definitely, if you are not keen on developing your own algorithm, pandas is a very handy library.